# JOIN the same column in the same table - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this tables:

TABLE **addonlist_final**

[image]

TABLE **addons**

[image]

First, I have to `JOIN` the same `addon_id` so I can get all the needed details(which I've already done). Then I want to `JOIN` the `column` with the same identity(addon_id) in the `table` then add the quantity to each other.

So far I have this code:

```
    <?php

include("conn.php");

echo "<table border='1' >";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Description</th>";
    echo "<th>Price</th>";
    echo "<th>Qty</th>";
    echo "<th>Total Cost</th>";
echo "</tr>";
$totaldue = 0;
$currentaddons = mysql_query("SELECT a.*, af.*
                            FROM addons AS a, addonlist_final AS af
                            WHERE a.addon_id = af.faddon_id and af.ftransac_id='2685'
                            ORDER BY af.timef DESC
                            ");

while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($currentaddons)){
    $desc = $rows['description'];
    $price = $rows['price'];
    $qty = $rows['quantity'];
    $totalcost = $price * $qty;
    $totaldue += $price * $qty;
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$desc</td>";
            echo "<td>$price</td>";
            echo "<td>$qty</td>";
            echo "<td>$totalcost</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

echo "<h3>Total Due: ".number_format($totaldue)."</h3>";

?>
```

This shows me this:

[image]

What I want to show is:

[image]

Is this possible with just one query? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looks like you want the `SUM()` aggregate function rather than another `JOIN` to me : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Comment: As an aside `mysql_*` functions are deprecated - don't use them : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: @CD001, yeah I'm still practicing `PDO`. So, `mysql_*` is my expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You uave to use `group by`

```
SELECT a.description, sum(af.quantity) as quantity,price
FROM addons AS a, addonlist_final AS af
WHERE a.addon_id = af.faddon_id and af.ftransac_id='2685'
group by a.description
ORDER BY af.timef DESC
```

Comment: `group by` is the right answer - but i would rather group by an int field instead of a varchar (e.g. `group by a.addon_id` instead of `group by a.description`)

Comment: Then you can not select the description on other dbms like oracle, thats why i have grouped by `a.description`

Comment: true - i didn't think about other dbms because this question is clearly about mysql - but on other dbms, i'll still at least include the addon_id (e.g. `group by a.addon_id, a.description`) since the description is probably (at least in the db design) not unique

Comment: Works like magic. Thanks but how the line `sum(af.quantity) as quantity,price` works? Any link for additional info?

Comment: @ArchieZineg see the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)